# How do I get validation error for either invalid email or email field left blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to validate fields in a form where I want two different messages for two different problems with the input.

I have the following code:

```
validates_format_of :email, 
                    :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i,
                    :allow_blank => false
```

If the email field is left blank then the error message "Email is invalid" is shown in the website.

How can I get the validation to return a message saying the field cannot be blank if it is left out by the user, instead of just saying it is too short?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to handle this with 2 different validations (and make sure they don't both fire at the same time). So something like this:

```
validates_format_of :email,
                    :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i,
                    :allow_blank => true
validates_presence_of :email
```

The `validates_presence_of` handles making sure the email is not blank. And changing `validates_format_of` to use `:allow_blank => true` will make sure the formatting validation won't run if the email is blank.

In Rails 3.0+ you can also combine the two validations into a single one using [`validates`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates):

```
validates :email,
          presence: true,
          format: { with: /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i,
                    allow_blank: true }
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a separate validation for the blank case:

```
validates_presence_of :email    
validates_format_of :email, 
                    :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i,
                    :allow_blank => true
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another validation checking for presence separately, like:

```
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: YOUR_REGEX }
```